# Calculate rowSums for three-dimensional array without for-loop/apply

Tags: r

Take array `b_array`:

```
set.seed(123)
a_mtx = matrix(1:15,ncol=5)
b_mtx = matrix(seq(1,5,length.out=30),ncol=5)

b_array = 
  array(
    b_mtx,
    dim = 
      c(
        nrow(b_mtx),
        ncol(b_mtx), 
        nrow(a_mtx)
      )
    )
```

If I want to calculate the sum of each column of each "slice" or "sheet" of `b_array`, I can use `colSums` with its dimension argument:

```
colSums(b_array, dim = 1)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,]  8.068966  8.068966  8.068966
#[2,] 13.034483 13.034483 13.034483
#[3,] 18.000000 18.000000 18.000000
#[4,] 22.965517 22.965517 22.965517
#[5,] 27.931034 27.931034 27.931034
```

To do the same for row sums, I cannot use `rowSums`'s dimension argument, as it is treated differently, so I resort to an `apply`:

```
apply(b_array, 3, rowSums)
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 13.27586 13.27586 13.27586
#[2,] 13.96552 13.96552 13.96552
#[3,] 14.65517 14.65517 14.65517
#[4,] 15.34483 15.34483 15.34483
#[5,] 16.03448 16.03448 16.03448
#[6,] 16.72414 16.72414 16.72414
```

I wish to perform the same calculation on an array with much larger dimension, so that `apply` and other for-loop methods are not efficient.

Are there any alternative, truly vectorized methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option using `aperm`

```
t(colSums(aperm(b_array, perm = c(2, 3, 1))))
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 13.27586 13.27586 13.27586
#[2,] 13.96552 13.96552 13.96552
#[3,] 14.65517 14.65517 14.65517
#[4,] 15.34483 15.34483 15.34483
#[5,] 16.03448 16.03448 16.03448
#[6,] 16.72414 16.72414 16.72414
```

Comment: `aperm` creates a copy of the array, I believe, which would be hellacious on a large dataset.

Comment: Looks like this method is superior in terms of computational time and memory use. `aperm` uses 8.38 times less memory, and finishes almost 30 times faster.

Comment: How large is the dataset you used to demonstrate that `aperm` is faster? What did you use for the actual benchmarking? If the matrix isn't the same size -- or if it truly is as small as the sample data in the question -- then benchmarking it is both unnecessary and potentially misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The default thinking (I believe) with regards to the `MARGIN=` (second) argument to `apply` is that it means "the axis that is reduced" (when aggregating ... simplifying for effect here). However, another way of looking at it is that all other dimensions remain untouched.

The effective equivalent of `colSums(ary)`, for example, is `apply(ary, 2, sum)`, meaning *"keep axis 1 un-reduced"*. (`colSums` is actually done internally, not with `apply`.) So to extend the "all axes *except*" logic, let's realize for your `b_array` that you want the 1st and 3rd axes to remain, so doing

```
apply(b_array, c(1,3), sum)
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 13.27586 13.27586 13.27586
# [2,] 13.96552 13.96552 13.96552
# [3,] 14.65517 14.65517 14.65517
# [4,] 15.34483 15.34483 15.34483
# [5,] 16.03448 16.03448 16.03448
# [6,] 16.72414 16.72414 16.72414
```

is about as efficient as you can get (I think) in doing a "column" sum with an *n*-dimensional array.

**Edit**:

@markus' use of `aperm` is faster, across a wide range of matrix sizes, though it appears to converge at larger matrices.

```
ns <- c(10,50,100,1000)
set.seed(123)
arrays <- lapply(ns, function(n) array(runif(3*n*n), dim=c(n,n,3)))

mapply(identical,
       lapply(arrays, function(a) t(colSums(aperm(a, perm = c(2, 3, 1))))),
       lapply(arrays, function(a) apply(a, c(1,3), sum)))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  aperm10 = t(colSums(aperm(arrays[[1]], perm = c(2, 3, 1)))),
  aperm50 = t(colSums(aperm(arrays[[2]], perm = c(2, 3, 1)))),
  aperm100 = t(colSums(aperm(arrays[[3]], perm = c(2, 3, 1)))),
  aperm1000 = t(colSums(aperm(arrays[[4]], perm = c(2, 3, 1)))),
  apply10 = apply(arrays[[1]], c(1,3), sum),
  apply50 = apply(arrays[[2]], c(1,3), sum),
  apply100 = apply(arrays[[3]], c(1,3), sum),
  apply1000 = apply(arrays[[4]], c(1,3), sum),
  times=10
)
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
#    aperm10    19.1    25.5    46.74    39.55    59.2   105.8    10
#    aperm50    55.7    77.2    96.36    94.30   115.6   149.8    10
#   aperm100   231.2   247.2   267.14   258.35   295.5   301.8    10
#  aperm1000 47282.5 47568.4 49235.19 49581.85 50118.4 52034.4    10
#    apply10    53.7    59.1    78.42    63.15   105.6   123.5    10
#    apply50   263.9   282.3   318.08   306.60   366.4   383.0    10
#   apply100   637.7   686.6   712.65   710.75   741.5   799.7    10
#  apply1000 40173.7 52735.7 52170.08 54349.65 55692.9 57375.9    10
```

(I haven't tested memory use.)

Comment: Interesting. I'll test it out tomorrow and see if it can handle the larger matrix without crashing.